# What considerations should I make for a fire ring?

Tags: fireplace, outdoor

I'm trying to build a fire ring in my yard. My thought is that for the base I will get a run-of-the-mill fire pit insert (maybe something simple, [like this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/30-in-Portable-Galvanized-Metal-Round-Fire-Pit-Ring-Can-Backyard-Camping-Firepit-/131485827047?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e9d2a7fe7)). My plan is to dig a hole about half its height deep, place the insert, fill with sand and gravel (lava rock?) to ground level, and possibly place brick around the outside.

- I would like to have the brick cemented in place, is there a particular form of mortar or concrete which would be well suited to higher temperatures?
- If I do not put brick around the outside, what else should I do to make sure the insert does not move?
- Will bricks make it easier to remove ash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring won't move, really. The bricks would be more for aesthetics than anything. I wouldn't use mortar. It will be outside and constantly subject to warming and cooling cycles...not to mention water. Instead go with a dry stack brick (or, what I did, retaining wall blocks...they're a bit more substantial and stay in place).

As for ash removal, there's no real need to do that. But when you do need to do that, all you need is a shovel. What the ring is made of is really of no consequence in that regard.

I would spend the time to put in a proper crushed gravel base for the block work, though. A few inches of crushed rock tamped down well will give you a nice foundation for the block work.

FYI, Lowes/Home Depot usually sell a nice fire-ring kit. It will include the ring and blocks to surround it.

Answer (score 1):

The long and the short:

- Lava rock vs. gravel isn't important except aesthetically.
- Use mortar not concrete for binding (in general). All mortar is heat resistant, but you can look for mortar which includes fire clay or [get information about mixing your own here](http://www.traditionaloven.com/building/details/refractorymortar.shtml) (experience suggests that this step is strictly optional, but I will be doing that anyway).
- It seems that there are two types of ground level fire pits – ones which rely on temporary insert which is somehow staked down, and ones which are actually built into the ground.